# Visual Studio 2022 Android Device not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to create a Xamarin.Forms application based on Android. Now I have the problem that my connected Android device is not recognized in Visual Studio. Running "adb devices" shows the connected device. When running Android Studio I can also see the device listed - only in Visual Studio it is not shown in the list. In addition, also the Windows Device manager shows the the device in the portable devices category.

- I have enabled USB Debugging on the device
- I tried different cables
- Reset the USB authorization for the connected PC

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Adb in your terminal is probably running from a different path to what Visual Studio uses. Fix your paths.

Comment: You ran "adb devices" from where? Reboot PC, then VS menu Tools / Android / Android adb command prompt - "adb devices" - does that now show it?

Comment: I am using the "Tools->Android-Adb Command Prompt" so this is started from VS. When I run the command first it tells me that the adb server is not running and it will be started - just a line below the connected device shows up in the command prompt. But still not in the combo-box for debugging

Comment: On the same machine, is Visual Studio 2019 normal？

Comment: I have to double check, because VS 2019 is not installed

Comment: Uhmmm just had this after I tried updating .net maui from the visual studio installer. Had to reboot a couple of times and used adb kill-server, adb start-server from command line before starting visual studio 2022 preview. (Note you may try shutdown and start as these are subtly different to restart in windows).

Comment: This solved it for me  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development#install-usb-drivers

Comment: @Porter, What part of that page?  It's pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Visual Studio Installer from your Start menu.

Select more->repair. Use this operation to try to repair.

You can also try other Android devices to check, if it still doesn't work, please check your Android SDK.

Comment: After uninstalling all other related Android development (e.g. Android Studio) the device is discovered. So it seems it was really a side effect. Anyway this took me a long time of my life to find the issue :-) Would be better if there is some kind of diagnosis in VS

Answer (score 0):

Running the "adb devices" command in the abd command prompt worked for me. VS 2022 was not showing any devices including the emulated ones untill I ran that command. Thanks. This is a good fix for an issue that has plagued VS for years.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34619518)